# generating api without artifacts

Tags: web-services, rest

We have a requirement, saying that generating api without artifacts.
Means there will be no WADL, WSDL, and no services.
As per discussion we need to sniff on a port and generate some sort of WADL?
I don’t know how to implement, any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the python service on google app engine I have found theme helpful in the past